# TSQL CASE Logic for WHERE clause using multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is returning rows from my user table. This data is picked by the user on the front end where the can define the type of user they are looking for as well as the users.

For example, there are 3 levels of users: `lvl1Mgr`, `lvl2Mgr`, `lvl3Mgr`. The user will pick the level they want to search on and then provide a list of people.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @searchType VARCHAR(5) = 'lvl1'
DECLARE @people TABLE (userID INT);

INSERT INTO @people (userID) VALUE (1)
INSERT INTO @people (userID) VALUE (2)
INSERT INTO @people (userID) VALUE (3)

SELECT
    u.first,
    u.last,
    u.email,
    u.lvl1Mgr,
    u.lvl2Mgr,
    u.lvl3Mgr 
FROM 
    USERS as u
WHERE
    u.field = 2
AND
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN @searchType = 'lvl1' THEN u.lvl1Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people)
            WHEN @searchType = 'lvl2' THEN u.lvl2Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people)
            WHEN @searchType = 'lvl3' THEN u.lvl3Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people)
        END
    )
```

I am trying to figure out how to do the final `AND` clause in my `WHERE` statement. Depending on the `@searchType` that was selected, it will determine which column we are looking in to see if any of the provided users exist.

Doesn't seem to like my `IN`  part of the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard it argued that this is not as bad as it looks becase the @searchType is constant and the SQL Query plan will do a predicate push on the variable @SearchType and know what you want.

```
SELECT u.fld1
  FROM USERS u
WHERE
    u.field = 2
  AND (    (@searchType = 'lvl1' AND u.lvl1Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people))
        OR (@searchType = 'lvl2' AND u.lvl2Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people))
        OR (@searchType = 'lvl3' AND u.lvl3Mgr IN (SELECT userID FROM @people))
      )
```

Comment: I am sure this will return exactly what OP is looking for, Good one +1

Comment: I think this will work. Is it possible to make this whole `AND` optional? For example, if I didn't select a `@searchType`, then I don't want this to run. On all my other statements, I ended up doing an `OR NOT EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM @table` for example. If @searchType is NULL, I wan't to pretend this whole `AND` block doesn't exist essentially.

Comment: If you add  OR (@SerchType IS NULL )  as one more or case then that might be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off picking the manager in the case and then doing the IN.

```
(
    CASE 
        WHEN @searchType = 'lvl1' THEN u.lvl1Mgr 
        WHEN @searchType = 'lvl2' THEN u.lvl2Mgr
        WHEN @searchType = 'lvl3' THEN u.lvl3Mgr
    END IN (SELECT userID FROM @people)

)
```

Comment: This might return wrong results, OP wants @lvl1mgr =  userid from people, what if there are 2 id's assigned to `u.lvl1Mgr`

Comment: It seems like lvl1Mgr is a single value to me (per row), so the CASE is just going to choose which manager to consider and then look it up in the @people table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
DECLARE @searchType VARCHAR(5) = 'lvl1'
DECLARE @people TABLE (userID INT);
DECLARE @users TABLE(lvl1 int,lvl2 int,lvl3 int)

INSERT INTO @people select 1
INSERT INTO @people select 2
INSERT INTO @people select 3

INSERT INTO @users
SELECT 0,2,3 UNION
SELECT 4,2,3

SELECT * FROM @users u
WHERE 
(CASE 
      WHEN @searchType = 'lvl1' THEN u.lvl1
      WHEN @searchType = 'lvl2' THEN u.lvl2
      WHEN @searchType = 'lvl3' THEN u.lvl3
END) in (SELECT UserID FROM @people)
```